# Create dummies conditionally to the following row

Tags: r

I have a panel dataset with different IDs in different years until 2018.

```
Year  ID 
2015  111
2016  111
2017  111
2018  111
2003  222
2004  222
2005  222
2006  222
2011  333
2012  333
2013  333
2014  333
```

I would like to create a third dummy variable which takes the value of 1 in the year the observation ends if it is before 2018 (which is the end of my observation period) in order to have at the end the following:

```
Year  ID   Dummy
2015  111    0
2016  111    0
2017  111    0
2018  111    0
2003  222    0
2004  222    0
2005  222    0
2006  222    1
2011  333    0
2012  333    0
2013  333    0
2014  333    1
```

I am doing it in order to prepare my panel data before creating a survival analysis. I thought to put together an if statement conditional to the next row in the ID column to be different from the previous one while the according year being different from 2018 but I can't pull up the code. Can someone help?

Comment: 2013 is a year before 2018, but its dummy value is 0, for example.

Comment: Yes because the ID is different, if it goes up to 2018, then there is no need for a Dummy= to 1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)

df[, Dummy := as.integer(Year == max(Year) & Year < 2018), by = ID]

df
#     Year  ID Dummy
#  1: 2015 111     0
#  2: 2016 111     0
#  3: 2017 111     0
#  4: 2018 111     0
#  5: 2003 222     0
#  6: 2004 222     0
#  7: 2005 222     0
#  8: 2006 222     1
#  9: 2011 333     0
# 10: 2012 333     0
# 11: 2013 333     0
# 12: 2014 333     1
```

Answer (score 2):

An option with `tidyverse`

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
     group_by(ID) %>%
     mutate(Dummy = +(Year == max(Year) & Year < 2018))
```